# How do I attach an image to a particular part of background with resize considered in CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, css, resize, window, background-image

Let's say my background is an image of a boombox such as: https://ibb.co/hCZSWt2
I have the background image style set to `background-size: cover` so it will resize properly with the window.

How do I "attach" a button to a part of that background, so that if the window is resized, the button will always remain in the same place, in relation to the background image.
(i.e. if they hit a button on one of the cassette decks, I can make a song play).

Currently, when I use `position: absolute` I can get it to be placed properly for my screen size, but when I use Chrome's inspector to see the mobile view, that throws off the location of the button in relation to the background. I anticipate this will need to use JavaScript's `vh` and `vw` properties to calculate where the button should go on window resize, but if anyone could provide a simple example that would help a ton!

Comment: Hi @DEGEN glad you recieved an answer, just for future reference try to show a simple break down of your current code, it will help you recieve more responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try using top/left/right/bottom attribute. You can set them to percentages so they *should* shift with the page resizing. If the discrepancy is too much however, you can use `@media` to change the css once you reach a certain window size. An example:

```
    #yourbutton{
        position: absolute;
        top: 15%;/*meaning it's top edge will be 15% of the page height away 
    from the top edge of the page*/
        left: 20%;
        /*You may want to set height and width to percentages as well to 
    make the buttons smaller should the screen size be too small*/
    }
    
    /*If the discrepancy piles up too much when the width/height is x 
    pixels*/
    @media (max-width: 900px) {
        left: 10%/*or something*/;
    }
```

If the answer worked for you, please consider accepting it!